# Find Point on a line based on 3rd point tangent to that line

Tags: c#, geometry, euclidean-distance

Finding distance to a point from a line defined by two points is well answered, [Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment) . Within that answer http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/ illustrates the line P1, P2 with point P3 tangent to the line showing how to determine distance to that point. This is a GPS application so the heading of the line is already determined and I would like to not use point slope formula or intercept with its limitations.

I would like to determine the point back on the line where the tangent intersects that line from P3 defined by P1 P2. Thank you in advance.

Edit:

I have a solution but its a bit cumbersome, but maybe not, it certainly works:

```
1) Calculate distance to point by 2 point line to P3 but don't take abs value 
2) If distance < 0 then side = 1 else side = -1 
3) dist = abs(distance) 
4) rad2 = heading + PI/2 * side //tangent is always 90 degrees to line
5) sin rad2*dist + P3.x = point Q.x 
6) cos rad2*dist + P3.y = point Q.y
```

Seems to work no matter the side the point is on

[image: sketch]

Comment: Can you add a sketch maybe. I am having trouble visualizing the request.

Comment: The image shows a line. Point P is also known and is P3 as above. I want to determine Q
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bTFIg.gif

Comment: Do I get you right - in your case P1, P2, and P3 are known, and you also know the tangent vector?

Comment: Yes, the tangent is 90 degrees to the line P1, P2. However the point can be on either side of the line. Also by calculating the distance of a point to a line defined by 2 points (Paul Bourke link), i also know the length of that tangent from the line to the point P3. Easily calculating the coordinates of "Q" is what i am after.

Comment: Paul's article gives a formula for calculating the coordinates of the intersection point (x, y). Isn't it good enough for you?

Comment: You want the point `Q` on a known line closest to another point `P`?

Comment: The article refers to falling within the point segment only, does it not?

Comment: No, the point can be anywhere along the line.

Comment: I'm not sure how to code    ||P2-P1|| ^2   to derive u. Is it ((P2.x - P1.x) - (P2.y-P1.y)) ^2  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a line is known by the equation `A*x+B*y+C=0` and a point *P* is outside the line with coordinates `(P_x,P_y)` then the point **on the line** closest to *P* is

```
x = (A^2*P_y-A*B*P_x-B*C)/(A^2+B^2)
y = (B^2*P_x-A*B*P_y-A*C)/(A^2+B^2)
```

Also the minimum distance of point *P* to the line is

```
d = ABS(A*P_x+B*P_y+C)/SQRT(A^2+B^2)
```

**Edit 1**

The equation of an infinite line passing through two points `(x_1,y_1)` and `(x_2,y_2)` is

```
A*x+B*x+C=0
(y_1-y_2)*x + (x_2-x_1)*y + (x_1*y_2-x_2*y_1) = 0
```

**Edit 2**

If the line is given from point `(Q_x,Q_y)` and direction `(e_x,e_y)` then the equation coefficients are

```
A = -e_y
B =  e_x
C = Q_x*e_y - Q_y*e_x
```

Comment: But the line is not known by the equation. Thanks for your answer, it is very good when the equation is known. I would like to only use P1 and P2 defining an infinite line where P3 can be anywhere along that line.

Comment: So how is the line defined? 1) Two points, 2) Point and Direction, 3) equation, 4) other construct.

Comment: 1. Two points derived from a point and a heading. I have a solution but its a bit cumbersome:     

1) Calculate distance to point by 2 point line to P3.     2) If distance < 0 then side = 1 else side = -1       3) dist = abs(distance)      4) rad2 = heading+PI/2*side     5) sin*rad2*dist + P3.x = point x     6)cos*rad2*dist + P3.y = point y

Comment: So edited the answer in order to find the line equation coefficients `A`, `B` and `C` from a point and a direction.

Comment: is e_x and e_y a normalized vector?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. It works with scalar multiples also. This is because `A*x+B*y+C=0` is the same line as `2A*x+2B*y+2C=0` and the coefficients are derived from `e_x` and `e_y` by multiplications and additions (linear operations).